# Tags in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, tags

I am new to MongoDB.

I have a product which can have multiple tags. I saw tutorials where the collection was like:

```
{
    _id: 1234,
    tags: ["stationery","electronics"]
}
{
    _id: 456,
    tags: ["home","electronics"]
}
{
    _id: 135,
    tags: ["books","stationery"]
}
```

I have a fixed list of tags. All my products will belong to these tags. Now my question is how to store such a list so that when a new product is added I can display this list and ask user to select tags only from this list?

Should I make another document called Tags and save reference in each collection? If I do this then while searching for products belonging to say Books category I will have to run 2 queries.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store tags like you see in tutorials.

```
{
    _id: 1234,
    tags: ["stationary","electronics"]
}
```

This allows for easy queries. Now, to serve your tag-adding UI, I'd create a separate collection "tags", which would consist of very simple documents

```
{ name: 'stationary' }
{ name: 'electronics' }
{ name: 'books' }
```

(mongodb will create an `_id` field on them, but you don't care about it).

So your UI will read documents from this collection and use `name` property to populate `tags` property of products.

Comment: Thanks. One thing more - I should make it non-editabled right, otherwise there will be just too many writes?

Comment: I mean the name of tags shouldn't be edited. If that happens I will need to update all products to reflect new tag name.

Comment: curious to know if it would be good to include tags as a sub-document inside categories for blog posts?